# Error when I duplicate laravel project and show me the last view

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a Laravel 5.3 project which was created 5 months ago, today I made a duplicate from the project and I made some changes into the code.

When I edit the views in a blade.php file my project which I edited showed me the last project view, I made a new route in the new laravel project and in the routes works well, but still shows the last project view.

It's funny because the js files works pretty well, but the view doens't work. for example, I edit the profile.blade.php file and it shows the content from the last project, if I writte something new in the other view from the last project, it shows in the new project.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your views/routes are compiled/cached.

> The ***storage directory*** contains your **compiled Blade templates**, file
>   based sessions, **file caches**, and other files generated by the
>   framework.
>
> The ***bootstrap directory*** contains files that bootstrap the framework
>   and configure autoloading. This directory also houses a cache
>   directory which contains framework generated files for performance
>   optimization such as the route and services cache files.

Run these commands

```
php artisan view:clear           - Clear all compiled view
php artisan optimize --force     - Optimize the framework for better performance
php artisan config:cache         - Create a cache file for faster configuration loading
php artisan route:cache          - Create a route cache file for faster route registration
```

Comment: Thank you so much xdevnull, you saved me. I'm a beginner in Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

Disable opcache from php.ini or use:

ini_set('opcache.enable', 0);